Clarification of the effective type restriction in C
I am trying to understand the precise meaning of paragraphs 6 and 7 of Section 6.5 of the C18 Standard.  Paragraph 6 defines the "effective type" of an object and 7 states in part "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types...a type compatible with the effective type of the object,...".
The following example is from an article on the C memory model.  A function
short g(int *p, short *q) {
  short z = *q; *p = 10; return z;
}

is called in the following context:
union int_or_short { int x; short y; } u = { .y = 3 };
int *p = &u.x; // p points to the x variant of u
short *q = &u.y; // q points to the y variant of u
return g(p, q); // g is called with aliased pointers p and q

The author claims this exhibits undefined behavior.  This is explained by considering an execution of the inlined version of the code:
union int_or_short { int x; short y; } u = { .y = 3 };
int *p = &u.x; // p points to the x variant of u
short *q = &u.y; // q points to the y variant of u
// g(p, q) is called, the body is inlined
short z = *q; // u has variant y and is accessed through y -> OK
*p = 10; // u has variant y and is accessed through x -> bad

The article states

The assignment *p = 10 violates the rules for effective types.  The memory area where p points to contains a union whose variant is y of type short, but is accessed through a pointer to variant x of type int. This causes undefined behavior.

If I understand the argument correctly, the object pointed to by p (or q) has an effective type of short, and the last statement is accessing that object through an lvalue of type int, which is not compatible with short, hence a violation of paragraph 7 of the C Standard quoted above.   But does the write *p=10 really count as an access to the stored value of the object?
Can someone explain, with reference to the language in the Standard, why, or why not, this code exhibits undefined behavior?
What about the following code:
union int_or_short { int x; short y; } u = { .y = 3 };
short z = u.y;
u.x = 10;

I always thought this code is perfectly legal (no undefined behavior), but if the first code is a violation, why isn't this one?   Why would *p=10 count as an access to the stored value of the object and u.x=10 not?  Both accesses are writes using an lvalue of type int.

Regarding

union int_or_short { int x; short y; } u = { .y = 3 };
int *p = &u.x;
short *q = &u.y;


, you write:

If I understand the article correctly, the object pointed to by p (or q) has an effective type of short,

If we interpret that as the article seems to mean, that p does not point to an int, then such a claim is not consistent with the C language spec.  It seems to be trying to apply a rule from C17 6.5/6 that (loosely speaking) an object's effective type is determined by the type of the value most recent stored in it, but that rule does not apply here.
According to the spec,

The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if
any.

(C17 6.5/6)
Pointer p points to u.x, which has declared type int.  That is not changed by the fact that the storage for u.x overlaps the storage for u.y.  Nor, for that matter, by the fact that the storage for both those objects overlaps the storage for u.
The rules about determining type by the value stored are later in that paragraph, but they apply only to objects having no declared type. The only objects contemplated by the language spec that do not have a declared type are dynamically allocated objects.
Perhaps the authors of the article got confused between allocated objects and objects accessed via pointers.  Allocated objects can be accessed only via pointers, but not all accesses via pointers are to allocated objects.  The rules for effective type are concerned with the nature of the object itself, not the means of access to it.
Moreover,

does the write *p=10 really count as an access to the stored value of the object?

[revised:]
Yes. "Access" is a defined term in the spec, meaning "to read or modify the value of an object" (C17 3.1/1). But that is not an issue.  The effective type of *p is the declared type of the object to which it points, u.x, which is int. Furthermore, if, contrary to fact, we were talking about a dynamically allocated object, then the spec would have this to say about that assignment (still paragraph 6.5/6):

For all other accesses to an object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is
simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.

So no, even if an allocated object were in play, there would be no issue with that assignment.
Of course, there is also no issue with performing the analogous assignment directly rather than via a pointer.

The article is available here: https://doi.org/10.1007/s10817-016-9369-1.  This is the exact quote: "The assignment *p=10 violates the rules for effective types.  The memory area where p points to contains a union whose variant is y of type short, but is accessed through a pointer to variant x of type int. This causes undefined behavior."

@SteveSiegel, this answer responds to the question as posed.  You should read Eric's answer carefully, however: he makes a persuasive argument that the article does not intend to make the claim you say it does.

I didn't find the argument persuasive but I have edited the question to include both the original and inlined versions.   I don't see what difference the inlining makes.  Do you think your argument that there is no undefined behavior applies to the original code as well?

@SteveSiegel, based on your update to the question, I don't think you've understood Eric's remarks, the central point being that the code you're asking about (he argues) should not be analyzed according to the C language specifications in the first place.  Rather, it should be understood as using C syntax as pseudocode to illustrate a claim about the preceding, non-inlined version.  I do think the article is flawed, but it does not necessarily intend to make the specific flawed claim you have attributed to it.  Nevertheless, the question can still be answered as posed, as I have done.

Let's forget about the inlined version, which may, or may not, be considered pseudocode.  Just focus on the original version, which includes a definition of a function g, and a specific call to g.  Do you believe that program has undefined behavior?  That is what the author claims.

No, @SteveSiegel.  That's a fundamentally different question than you first posed and that two people already answered.  You are welcome to ask it as a new question, but it is contrary to our accepted practice here to change the question in a way that changes its meaning after you already have answers.  I would ordinarily roll back those changes, and I may still do so, but I am conflicted because you also introduced some improvements in the same edit.

I don't agree it is fundamentally different — the two versions (original and inlined) appear semantically equivalent and either both have undefined behavior or neither does.  But as that seems to be a controversial view, I've taken your advice and started a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79091407/strict-aliasing-and-unions-in-c

The paper’s author, Robbert Krebbers, does not assert the C code shown with g inlined has undefined behavior. That code is only provided to illustrate the inlining for the reader.
In a comment, you provided a link to the paper (which should have been provided in the question). Reading the paper, Krebbers talks about obtaining the code you show by inlining a function g into other code that calls it:

We will inline part of the function body of g to indicate the incorrect usage of aliased pointers during the execution of the example.

This transformation muddles the semantics—when the paper shows this new code with g inlined, it is not stated whether this new C code is intended to be reinterpreted as it appears, with the union definition visible when the inlined code from g is compiled or that this inlining is merely for display to the user of what happens when the code from g, with its original in situ interpretation, is moved into the place where g is called. In other words, in this latter case, the new code Krebbers shows after the function is inlined is merely a pseudo-code illustration of how inlining changes the code; it is not actual C code to be compiled.
The original g has parameters int *p, short *q, and no union declaration is visible. In this context, the compiler may assume *p and *q do not alias. At the point where g is called, the union declaration is visible, and it is apparent that u.x and u.y do alias. If we take the latter hypothesis above, that g is interpreted in situ, then everything is consistent:

When compiling g, the compiler may assume *p and *q do not alias.
It is an error to call g with pointers that cause aliasing. Even though, at the call site, the compiler can see that *p and *q alias, g was analyzed in an earlier context where this was not visible.
The inlining of g brings the analyzed semantics of g (for example, the compiler’s internal representation of g) into the call site without reinterpreting the source code of g.

Given this, when Krebbers says that *p = 10; in the inlined code violates “the rules for effective types” (actually C 2018 6.5 7, often called the aliasing rule(s)), they are saying that the combination of the code of g with the pointers passed to it violates the aliasing rule. That is correct. Krebbers is only stating that the code in g has undefined behavior, not that the illustrative inlined code would have undefined behavior if it were compiled anew.

I'm inclined to accept this interpretation of the article, that it does not intend to make the claim attributed to it in the question.

I don't understand why "the compiler may assume *p and *q do not alias."  The only reason the compiler may assume that is because if they did alias, there would be undefined behavior.  The paper argues there is undefined behavior because "The assignment *p=10 violates the rules for effective types. The memory area where p points to contains a union whose variant is y of type short, but is accessed through a pointer to variant x of type int. This causes undefined behavior."  That argument applies to the original code with function g and the inlined version I quoted.

The article still seems to make incorrect claims, however.  In particular: "The memory area where p points to contains a union whose variant is y of type short, but is accessed through a pointer to variant x of type int. This causes undefined behavior." C permits a different union member to be accessed than was last written.  I think even C++'s stricter rules allow a different member to be written than was last written.

I edited the question to include the link to the paper and both versions (the original and inlined) of the code.   I don't think the inlining makes any difference to the argument.  I don't see anything in the standard that would distinguish between the original and inlined versions.

@SteveSiegel: Re “I don't understand why "the compiler may assume *p and *q do not alias." The only reason the compiler may assume that is because if they did alias, there would be undefined behavior.”: Yes, that is the reason. Either *p and *q do not alias or the behavior is undefined. If they do not alias, the compiler may behave as if they do not alias. If they do alias, the behavior is not defined, in which case any behavior conforms to the requirements of the C standard (none), including behaving as if they do not alias.

So, you're saying that in compiling g, the compiler may assume that *p and *q do not alias, on the basis that one is an lvalue of type short and the other is an lvalue of type int (because if they did alias it's UB).  That sounds very plausible.  But by that same logic, couldn't we then argue that in compiling union { int x; short y; } u; u.x = 3; u.y = 4; the compiler may assume that u.x and u.y do not alias, and could for instance reorder the stores? But that conclusion seems absurd because it seems clear that the standard intends such code to work "as expected".

Or, if pointers are the issue, then consider union { int x; short y; } u; *&u.x = 3; *&u.y = 4;, which seems like it should be handled identically to u.x = 3; u.y = 4;.

So we seem to be in a dilemma between two very unintuitive results.  Either "obviously correct" code like u.x = 3; u.y = 4; is actually UB (in which case unions become almost unusable), or there exists a program whose behavior may change (or become undefined) when some of its code is moved from the caller function to the callee.

@NateEldredge On the caller side where the union is definitely visible, there's also the 6.2.6 Representation of types: "Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object representation, which object
representation is used shall not affect the value of the result. Where a value is stored in an object using a type that has more than one object representation for that value, it is unspecified which representation is used, but a trap representation shall not be generated." Maybe that applies here? The caller can't know what the function did to the union.

@Lundin: That seems to be intended for things like negative zero for sign-magnitude or ones-complement integers. But I think this issue arises even on typical implementations where object representations for integer types are unique.

@NateEldredge It's mentioned in the context of representation of unions and effective type.

@EricPostpischil: you write "If they do alias, the behavior is not defined".  Why is the behavior undefined?   Which constraint in the Standard is violated?   Whatever your answer to that question, why does that answer not also apply to the last code in my question, which does not use pointers?

Is this about the strict aliasing rule? Or do unions get around that? Maybe the author thinks this is a strict aliasing violation?

Interpreting the Standard in a manner with the way clang and gcc treat unions would require either recognizing that nearly all accesses of the form someUnion.arrayMember[index] either invoke UB, or that they have semantics which differ from (*((someUnion.arrayMember)+(index))), which is the defined meaning of the [] operator.  The former could make sense if one recognizes that the Standard made no systematic effort to ensure that it exercises jurisdiction over all constructs that implementations should process usefully, but that lattter notion contradict clang and gcc's philosophy.

@Barmar I think so. You're good if you access union members through the union, otherwise strict aliasing rules apply.

@JohnBollinger Just for clarification regarding C++: In C++ writing to the inactive union member (which then becomes active) is only allowed in very specific expression forms that need to be rooted in an expression referring to the union object itself, deriving the member by member access (.) and array indexing. So effectively this requires the union definition to be visible at the point of the expression. Changing the active member through a pointer to the member is not possible at all via assignment (regardless of whether or not the union definition is visible).

@user17732522: that makes a lot of sense.  I wish the C Standard said something like that, it would clear up many questions.

Defect Report 028 was written between C89 and C99 to address the question about whether operations using pointers to union members should have the same semantics as operations performed on union members directly, and stated without justification that using pointers to perform actions which would be Implementation-Defined if performed on union members directly invoked Undefined Behavior.  I think the Effective Type rule was intended to say that operations with pointers that would have standard-defined rather than implementation-defined behavior if those pointers happened to identify members of unions should have their behavior defined likewise, but it failed to say anything about the actual situation Defect Report 028 had been written to address.
What has always been needed to make type-based aliasing really work, but what the Standard has failed to articulate, is that it is intended to indicate when compilers must accommodate the possiblity that accesses that have no fresh visible relationship to something of a common type might alias.  Given the code:
useFloatPtr(&someUnion.floatMember);
useUnsignedPtr(&someUnion.unsignedMember);
useFloatPtrAgain(&someUnion.floatMember);

a compiler that isn't being wilfully blind would have no trouble noticing that all three of the pointers passed to functions are freshly derived from a common type.  If the functions are processed independently of the calling code, a compiler reason would have no reason to expect that the passed storage would be used elsewhere as something of a different type but also no reason to care.  If the functions are in-lined, a compiler should be able to see the derivations of different pointer types that occur between the different function executions.
That's a very different situation from:
useFloatPtrAndUnsignedPtr(&someUnion.floatPtr, &someUnion.unsignedPtr);

where a compiler that generates code for that function may have reason to consolidate accesses via the float* across accesses via the unsigned*, and no reason to know it shouldn't do so.
Any implementation that was making a good faith effort to be compatible with existing programs and practices when the Standard was written would need to support the usage where each function would only access a union via pointer to one of its members, whether they did so as a consequence of not being able to in-line functions, or as a consequence of observing the derivation of union-member pointer types that occurred between the functions.  It would have been awkward to write a standard in a way that would require implementations to recognize pointer derivations in circumstances when many implementations would have no reason to care about their absence, and the expenditure of ink would have helped neither in circumstances where compiler writers make a good faith effort to support existing practice, nor in circumstances where compiler writers do not make such a good faith effort.

Thanks for the interesting background.  But what is your conclusion?   Based on the existing C Standard, does any of the code in the question have undefined behavior?  Why or why not?

@SteveSiegel: Under the existing standard, any code that accesses any part of a struct or union using any lvalue of anything other than a character type or that struct or union type invokes UB.  If theArray is any non-character array-type member of a struct or union, every evaluation or assignment to an lvalue of the fom structOrUnion.theArrayt[index] invokes UB.  Not a problem if UB is recognized as accommodating the possibility "Do the obviously useful thing if there is one", which is the only sensible way of interpreting the Standard.

@SteveSiegel: Clang and gcc pretend that the Standard provides for arbitrary use of pointers to struct-member types to access those struct members, and treats the particular syntax someUnion.arrayMember[index] as being uniquely capable of accessing elements of that array, but nothing in the Standard forbids compilers from treating both such constructs as UB, beyond the fact that doing so would make it obvious that the authors of the Standard weren't making a serious effort to ensure that no useful constructs were characterized as UB, but relied on compilers writers' desire to be useful.

"Under the existing standard, any code that accesses any part of a struct or union using any lvalue of anything other than a character type or that struct or union type invokes UB.":  how do you reach that conclusion from the text in the Standard?   The Standard says you can take the address of an lvalue (so int *p=&u.x; is fine) and you can do *p=rhs; if the effective type of the object referenced is the type of *p.  Where do you see this restriction on use of pointers to members of structs/unions?

@SteveSiegel: The Standard exhaustively lists all of the types that may be used to access an object of struct or union type.  The Standard provides for accessing a struct or union of type T via an lvalue of type T, an lvalue of a struct or union type containing T, or a character type.  There is no provision for using an lvalue of a struct or union's member type to access a struct or union object, perhaps because there would seldom be any need to use such an lvalue to access a struct or union from which the lvalue was not freshly visibly derived.

@SteveSiegel: If one were to tweak the wording of the Standard slightly to say that storage which is accessed within some particular context using an lvalue of some particular type may only be accessed via an lvalue which is within that context freshly visibly associated with one of the following types, the rule would accommodate the vast majority of use cases without any provision for struct or union members (contexts could be drawn broadly or narrowly, provided an implementation treated the second context as least as broadly as the first).

@SteveSiegel: In the 1990s, it was obvious to almost everyone but the maintainers of gcc that any non-garbage compiler should recognize that ((unsigned short*)pointerToFloat)[1] += 0x80; might access an object of type float, without the authors of the Standard having to patronizingly expend ink saying so.  If one thinks about it, with the execption of saying that an object may be accessed using an lvalue of its own type, all of the other things listed are things for which a compiler writer might not otherwise have expected to alias seemingly unrelated objects.

@SteveSiegel: I think what happened years ago was that before gcc added type-based aliasing logic, earlier stages of compilation effectively converted loads, stores, and pointer-arithmetic operations to use the associated pointer types, and then dropped type information from the pointers themselves, which would have been fine absent attempts to perform type-based aliasing analysis without such information.  Unfortunately, rather than fix that weakness, the maintainers of gcc have sought to instead gaslight the community into viewing code that doesn't fit their deficient model as "broken".
