Strict Aliasing and Unions in C
Consider the following C program (which is based on an example from this article):
#include <stdio.h>

short g(int *p, short *q) {
  short z = *q; *p = 10; return z;
}

int main(void) {
  union int_or_short { int x; short y; } u = { .y = 3 };
  int *p = &u.x;
  short *q = &u.y;
  short r = g(p, q);
  printf("%hd %d\n", r, u.x);
}

Does this program exhibit undefined behavior?   Please explain by referring to specific passages in the C17 Standard.

Please [edit] your question to tell us what you think, and why.

Why should there be? You've initialised member y, and read it, before doing anything with member x, which the function writes to, and main reports. In the convoluted code.

Hmm, IIRC, due to anti-aliasing, compiler can reorder short z = *q; *p = 10; effectively into *p = 10; short z = *q; (leading to a different answer than what one would think) or parallel execution of *p = 10;  and short z = *q; as compiler can assume short * and int * do not point to the same place due to type differences (even though they do), potentially leading to a bus conflict/fault.  Thus I suspect it is UB.  Yet I don't want to venture down the rabbit hole of language lawyering on this beautiful day

@Someprogrammerdude: Why? Stack Overflow is for asking programming questions. This is a programming question. Users do not generally need to state what they think. There may be some types of questions where that is appropriate, but it is not here. Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a tutorial site where you are teaching students and use a pedagogical technique of starting with what they understand or think. It is perfectly fine for somebody to directly ask a question here.

This is in fact undefined behavior, as the union definition is not visible in the function g and therefore the compiler may assume that the p and q parameters (which point to incompatible types) point to distinct objects.
There's a nearly identical example given in section 6.5.2.3p9:

EXAMPLE 3 The following is a valid fragment:
union {
    struct {
        int alltypes;
    } n;
    struct {
        int type;
        int intnode;
    } ni;
    struct {
        int type;
        double doublenode;
    } nf;
} u;
u.nf.type = 1;
u.nf.doublenode = 3.14;
/* ... */
if (u.n.alltypes == 1)
if (sin(u.nf.doublenode) == 0.0)
/* ... */

The following is not a valid fragment (because the union type is not
visible within function f):
struct t1 { int m; };
struct t2 { int m; };
int f(struct t1 *p1, struct t2 *p2)
{
    if (p1->m < 0)
        p2->m = -p2->m;
    return p1->m;
}

int g()
{
    union {
        struct t1 s1;
        struct t2 s2;
    } u;
    /* ... */
    return f(&u.s1, &u.s2);
}


The second piece of code above is passing pointers to two members of the same union to a function where the union definition is not visible, followed by 1) a read of one member 2) a write of the other 3) a read of the first, just as in your example.

The part of the Standard you are quoting deals with a special case of a union whose members are structs: "One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible."  The union in the question does not contains structs so this passage does not apply.

@SteveSiegel: The examples in 6.5.2.3 speak to multiple things in the clause, not just paragraph 6, where the common initial sequence rules is given. The second code fragment in this example is not affected by the common initial sequence rule. That rule could make the behavior defined if its requirements were met. However, its requirements are not met in f, so it does not apply. So this code is an example of code that violates the aliasing rule.

It is a more interesting question why the code in g would be defined in main. Suppose in main we insert *p = 3;. This accesses the int, which is certainly allowed, but it also accesses the short member y. Nothing in the aliasing rule says this is allowed: int is not compatible with short, it is not a qualified version that is compatible, it is not a corresponding signed or unsigned type, it is not a qualified corresponding type, it is not an aggregate or union, and it is not a character type. So what rule actually makes unions work?

@EricPostpischil: Can you give a reference to the "aliasing rule" (in the Standard) and explain how the code in my question violates it?

Perhaps what makes the second piece of code invalid is that it reads from one field of the union and then reads from the other field (i.e., s1 and s2).  And the two fields have incompatible types.   A union can only hold one value at a time.  (This rule is relaxed for union fields which are structs sharing a common sequence, but only if the union definition is visible, as @EricPostpischil says.)   This is different from my code, which first reads one field of the union, then writes to the other --- that is a typical valid use of unions.  I'm really not sure.

Are you saying that if we were to move the declaration of union int_or_short to file scope, so that it is visible to g (even though not used in any way within g), that the code would be legal?  Then this would seem to say that a compiler may assume that int * does not alias short *, unless there is a union type in scope containing both int and short as members, in which case it may not make such an assumption.  That's quite counterintuitive.

@NateEldredge: for the code in the question, I don't think moving the union definition makes any difference.   Nothing in the C Standard makes any distinction based on the union definition being visible or invisible, with one exception.  The exception is the common sequence rule, which applies to a union of structs with common prefixes, but that doesn't apply to the code in the question.

@SteveSiegel: Note that according to the authors of clang and gcc, the meaning of the word "visible" in that part of the Standard is different from its meaning everwhere else, and even within the lvalue expression (&someUnion.structMember+intValuethatHappensToBeZero)->memberOfStruct, the type of the union would somehow not be visible when attempting to use the struct member access operator.

@EricPostpischil So what rule actually makes unions work? 6.5.2.3?

@oguzismail Why does there have to be only one rule?

@oguzismail: The "rule" that says that if clang and gcc didn't treat unions as being useful in at least some circumstances beyond those mandated by the Standard, the authors would be unable to pretend that the Standard is intended to fully enumerate all useful constructs that quality impementations should be expected to support.

I'm going to argue the behavior is well-defined.  There is nothing in the C Standard which is violated.
There is no rule in the Standard that says a union type must be visible at a point where the union members are accessed by pointers, or anything like that.  (There is such a requirement for code that reads from two different struct fields of a union with a common prefix, but that is not relevant here, since this code never attempts to read from two different fields, and there is no struct field.)
There is no constraint which prohibits two pointers of different types from being aliased.
There is a constraint on the type of an lvalue expression used to access an object, in paragraphs 6-7 of Sec. 6.5 of C17.  "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: ... a type compatible with the effective type of the object ...."
This code does not violate that constraint.  The effective type of the object designated by u.y is short, and that object is accessed by the lvalue expression, *q, of type short.   The effective type of the object designated by u.x is int, and that object is accessed by the lvalue expression *p of type int.   The objects happen to overlap, but that does not cause UB, just as the code not using pointers
z=u.y; u.x=10;

has no UB.  Put another way, any interpretation of the effective type rule which prohibits the code with pointers must also prohibit the code above without pointers, but everyone agrees the code without pointers is correct and in fact a standard way to use unions.
I can't find anything else in the Standard that could possibly imply UB in this program.
Having said all of that, I find the Standard to be completely confusing on these points, and there are probably other valid interpretations.
Note that if g had performed a read of *q and then a read of *p (without an intervening write), there would be a problem, because then one of those reads could be a trap representation, so UB.

A single-pass compiler wouldn't know where p and q came from. Given 6.5p7 it could assume p != q and hoist *p = 10 up and z = *q would be UB.

@oguzismail: The Standard lacks the terminology to distinguish T1 *p = &u.thing1; ... code that uses p... ; T2 *q = &u.thing2; ...code that uses q... versus code which takes the address of both p and q, and then uses both, but there has never been any reason for a compiler writer to fail to accommodate the latter unless they were not making a good faith effort to process useful programs correctly.  The Rationale observes that the type-based aliasing rules exist to avoid making compilers process all corner cases correctly, not to imply that compilers shouldn't try to correctly handle...

...any corner cases their customers might find useful.  The Standard waives jurisdicition over many constructs for which the authors would have viewed as a "quality of implementation" issue. The more obviously useful a construct would be, the less need there should be to mandate support.
